# MySQL Select From Multiple Structurally Identical Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate

Let me preface this by saying that yes I am aware that even a beginner DBA should probably know the answer to this question, but I have never had any formal training and I can't find the answer after quite a bit of Googling, so please go easy on me :)

I have a database containing 88 identical (in structure, not data) tables which total 20465 rows.  I am looking for a way to aggregate these so I can:

```
SELECT * FROM [aggregate] WHERE id = 'some unique value';
```

The (working but VERY slow) solution I came up with was to create a view by `select *` from each table and then `union` them together, however it is apparent to me when doing a search that this is not the correct way to do this. For example selecting ~200 records takes well over a minute.

This does not seem to be a use case for a join as the tables have no relation to one another, they simply contain the same kind of data.

I get the feeling that an index is what I am looking for, but I am unsure if I should be indexing the view (my Googling seems to indicate that this is not possible?) or if I am maybe not understanding indices properly.

Any tips in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! (even if it's just a link to some documentation).

Comment: My first question would be, "Why do you have that many identical tables?"

Comment: Does your view really use `union`? Since you should allow duplicates between the tables you should be using `union all`, which should also be a massive speed improvement.

Comment: Creating a VIEW definition, as a solution to a problem, often introduces problems that are bigger than the original problem. This isn't to jump on the "views are bad" bandwagon, but creating and using views *without understsanding* how those are processed in MySQL can lead to *significant* performance problems. (I address this in more detail in my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

The commenter is correct. Use `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`. `UNION ALL` doesn't attempt to deduplicate the rows, where `UNION` does. Deduplicating is a lot of work, even if there aren't any duplicates.

You need to use a series of UNION ALL operations to treat all these tables as one table.  That's how you do it.

If it were me I'd run this query once:

```
  CREATE new_table AS
             SELECT 1 source, * FROM table1
  UNION ALL  SELECT 2 source, * FROM table2
  UNION ALL  SELECT 3 source, * FROM table3
       etc etc ad nauseam
  UNION ALL  SELECT 88 source, * FROM table88
```

Then use `new_table` for all future work. I'd drop the 88 tables after that.

Answer (score 0):

It is *not* possible to declare an index for a view definition. (Google was right.)

You can however add an index on each of the 88 tables. Which indexes to create really depends on the data distribution, cardinality, and most importantly, the queries that run against these tables. Indexes are not a silver bullet. For some query patterns, there's no index that will help. So, before we start creating indexes...

---

**How views work in MySQL informs the observed performance problems**

Learning how a query that references a view definition gets processed in MySQL is the key to understanding why views can lead to performance problems that catch the uninitiated unawares.

It's too easy an answer to jump onto the "views are bad" bandwagon. And it doesn't really answer *why* performance with views is observed to be "bad".

The following is a bit of ramble... and could use a good edit.

---

With older versions of MySQL, an view definition is always materialized. In the MySQL vernacular, it's called a *derived table*. And the name they use for it make sense when you understand the order of operations. This same behavior is observed whether it's an inline view (a `SELECT` statement used as rowsource in the query), or a reference to a stored view (a `SELECT` statement stored as an object in the database.)

The performance problem comes in with the handling of predicates in the outer query. In older versions of MySQL, predicates in the outer query are *never* pushed into the view definition. Doesn't matter if the view is inline or stored.

As a simplified demonstration, consider this query:

```
SELECT v.mycol
  FROM ( SELECT t.mycol 
           FROM bigtable t
       ) v
 WHERE v.mycol = 'foo'
```

The order of operations in MySQL is to first run the query between the parens, and to materialize it as derived table. The performance is on the order of doing

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE v (mycol mydatatype);
INSERT INTO v (mycol) SELECT t.mycol FROM bigtable t;
```

For small tables that meet some specific requirements, MySQL will use the MEMORY engine. If a table doesn't meet the requirements, or exceeds a certain size, then MySQL spins it off to disk as a MyISAM table.

Once that operation is finished, the outer query can run. When this runs, `v` can be accessed like a regular table:

```
SELECT v.mycol
  FROM v
 WHERE v.mycol = 'foo'
```

With that query, MySQL has to evaluate `mycol` for *every* row in `v` (The derived table), to determine if a row matches or not. And that hurts, in terms of performance.

(With the latest version MySQL 5.7, the optimizer will (in some cases) actually create an index on the derived table. In older versions, MySQL would *never* create a index on a derived table. Ouch.

If our view query does a `SELECT * FROM bigtable`  (selecting every column, then the view is effectively making a copy the whole table. If the rows in `bigtable` are large, and the table contains a bloatload of rows, that can be an expensive operation.

If we store that query definition as VIEW in the database, that same set of operations is going to happen *every* time we query the view.

---

What I mean by "pushing" the predicates "into" the view query.

Contrast the above with what happens with a query like this:

```
 SELECT v.mycol
   FROM (
          SELECT t.mycol
            FROM bigtable t
           WHERE t.mycol = 'foo'
         ) v
   WHERE v.mycol = 'foo'
```

Notice that we have a `WHERE` clause on that inner query, between the parens. MySQL runs that inner query, it only retrieves rows from `bigtable` that satisfy that condition in the `WHERE` clause. If that's fairly selective, then the number of rows may be a significantly smaller set. And with that inner query, the MySQL optimizer can take advantage of an index with a leading column of `mycol` to efficiently satisfy the query. If `mycol` is the PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE KEY of bigtable, then the query is going to return at most one row. And that's a much smaller *derived table* to materialize.

And in this example, the predicate on the outer query is redundant. The `WHERE` clause on the outer query could be removed, and we're still guaranteed to get the same result.

---

In your particular case, MySQL is having to open 88 tables, obtain metadata locks, and obtain table locks (if it's MyISAM), etc.

As other answers (rightly) point out, the `UNION` operator in your query is causing a "unique sort" operation to identify and remove duplicate rows from the entire set. And that can be expensive.

**TL;DR**

*BOTTOM LINE*

Creating view definition is much more likely to create performance problems that are bigger and more problematic, than whatever problem was being addressed by creating the view definition.

In terms of performance, you would be much better off with a query that includes predicates for the query of each table. Assuming that you need every column (do you really need to return every column, or do you really only need a subset of them)

This query is going to run much faster:

```
  SELECT t01.* FROM mytable01 t01 WHERE t01.mycol = 'foo'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t02.* FROM mytable02 t02 WHERE t02.mycol = 'foo'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t03.* FROM mytable03 t03 WHERE t03.mycol = 'foo'
  ... 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t88.* FROM mytable88 t88 WHERE t88.mycol = 'foo'
```

That's especially if an appropriate index is available on `mycol` in each of the 88 tables.

When I have a statement that combines results from multiple queries like this (but not with 88 tables!), I will typically include a *discriminator column* which will allow me to identify which query returned the row.

```
  SELECT 't01' AS q, t01.* FROM mytable01 t01 WHERE t01.mycol = 'foo'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 't02' AS q, t02.* FROM mytable02 t02 WHERE t02.mycol = 'foo'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 't03' AS q, t03.* FROM mytable03 t03 WHERE t03.mycol = 'foo'
  ... 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 't88' AS q, t88.* FROM mytable88 t88 WHERE t88.mycol = 'foo'
```

From that first column in the resultset (`q`) I can determine which query returned a row.

What was the question?  I think you asked for some tips. I hope I've given you some things to consider.